# Is there a way to put overlay for a third-party web player which insert an iframe with <video></video> to dom?

Tags: html, video.js

I am using bambuser player https://bambuser.com/docs/playback/web-player/ to view my broadcasting video in real time. It injects an iframe to given id.

lets say if i have and div element like:

```
<div id="player">
```

ultimately the script provide a player like:

```
<div id="player">
<iframe>
  ....
    <video></video>
  ....
</iframe>
</div>
```

The problem i am facing now is to how i can add some overlays(like banners) to injected iframe's <
video> tag

Comment: Why do you want to put them in the video or even iframe? Can't you just overlay the banner on the main page on top of the page/video? The question is unclear and also too broad as it is can you narrow it down and add more specific problem?.

Comment: @Esko i can overlay the banner in main page, but in that case i have to handle responsiveness of that banner as same as that video behave. So i thought getting video class itself would be good choice

Comment: The banner and the iframe could be inside the player-div and contain 100% of it. That way both will always be the same size and you can use z-index to position banner on top.

Comment: @Esko in my case the iframe is generated and injected by videojs library so i have no control over iframe created. but what i am expecting is, find a way to capture injected iframe if possible or any alternative to show my banner as it appeared inside video